# program gives out incorrect values once at unsigned integer

Tags: c, int, scanf, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I am trying to print out each field of a line of information.
So the program prints out perfect until it gets to the size variable. It gives a value 28277 and then the rest of the program prints incorrect values if any at all. The first comment is the line entered and the rest are the values that are printed from the program. any help to figure out this error would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
        char permission[11];
        char username[32];
        char usergroup[32];
        unsigned char links;
        unsigned char day;
        unsigned int size;
        char month[4];
        char year[8];
        char filename[32];

        //-rw-rw-r-- 1 xsperopoulos xsperopoulos  225 Jun 20 18:55 a.out
        //Permission: -rw-rw-r--
        //Links: 1
        //Username: xsperopoulos
        //Usergroup: xsperopoulos
        //Size: 28277
        //Month:
        //Day: J
        //Year or Time Stamp:
        //Filename: 2
        printf("Please enter a line of text from ls -l:");
        scanf("%[^0-9]%c%s%s%5u%c%s%c%c",permission,&links,username,usergroup,&size,month,&day,year,filename);

        //permission
        printf("Permission: %s\n",permission);

        //links
        printf("Links: %c\n",links);

        //username
        printf("Username: %s\n",username);

        //usergroup
        printf("Usergroup: %s\n",usergroup);

        //size
        printf("Size: %5u\n",size);

        //month
        printf("Month: %s\n",month);

        //day
        printf("Day: %c\n",day);

        //year or timestamp
        printf("Year or Time Stamp: %s\n",year);

        //filename
        printf("Filename: %s\n",filename);
}
```

Comment: Check your scanf format string again.  The format specifiers and the arguments don't seem to match up.

Comment: The `permission` array is not big enough.